# String replacement in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby

I have a text like

```
details = "1. Command id = 22 Time = 2:30 <br> 2. Command id = 23 Time = 3:30"
```

Now I need to convert it into

```
"1. http://localhost:3000/command_id=22/home Time = 2:30 <br> 2. http://localhost:3000/command_id=23/home Time = 3:30"
```

I used regex and `gsub` but it will not do that as `gsub` will replace same string. Then there are some techniques using `sed` and `awk`.

To extract all ids like 22, 23, I used

```
details.scan(/Command id = [0-9]+/).join(",").scan(/[0-9]+/)
```

Any ideas how to do the above conversion?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Removing `Command id = ` from the string or extracting the ids or both?

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you just use

```
details.gsub(' Command id =', '')
```

It generates expected result

```
"1. 22 Time = 2:30 <br> 2. 23 Time = 3:30"
```

**EDIT:**

```
details.gsub('Command id = ', 'http://localhost:8000/')
```

It will generate

```
 "1. http://localhost:8000/22 Time = 2:30 <br> 2. http://localhost:8000/23 Time = 3:30"
```

Comment: I have edited my post.Can you please have a look into it.I want to generate http link .

Answer (score 2):

Simple regex

```
details.gsub(' Command id =', '')

#=> "1. 22 Time = 2:30 <br> 2. 23 Time = 3:30"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string.gsub('Command id =', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `Command id =` with an empty string

```
string.gsub(/\s*\bCommand\s+id\s+=/, "")
```

Comment: You could just provide a string pattern, i.e. `gsub('Command id = ', '')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this pure regex and get your expected output

```
sed 's/[^"]\+\([^ ]\+\)[^=]\+=\([^\.]\+.\)[^=]\+.\(.*\)/\1\2\3/' FileName
```

or

```
sed 's/Command id =\|details = //g' FileName
```

**Output :**

```
"1. 22 Time = 2:30 <br> 2. 23 Time = 3:30"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def parse_to_words(line)line.split ' '
end

line = "1. Command id = 22 Time = 2:30 <br> 2. Command id = 23 Time = 3:30"

words = parse_to_words line

output= words[0] +  
        " http://localhost:3000/command_id=" + 
        words[4] +
        "/home Time = " +
        words[7] + 
        " <br> " + 
        words[9] +
        " http://localhost:3000/command_id=" +
        words[13] + 
        "/home Time = " +
        words[16]
```

Output: `1. http://localhost:3000/command_id=22/home Time = 2:30 <br> 2. http://localhost:3000/command_id=23/home Time = 3:30`

Can of course be automated further